# Do I need to worry about the IV if I use a 32 byte random salt with SCrypt and AES-GCM?

Tags: aes, initialization-vector, gcm, salt, scrypt

I am encrypting a DEK (data encryption key) with a KEK (key encryption key). The KEK is generated from a password using scrypt with default parameters and a 32 byte randomly generated salt. The encryption algorithm is AES-GCM.

What are the implications for the IV in this case? Let's assume that the IV is initialized to 0 (96 bits of 0s). If I re-use an IV with a key then this is bad news. Since the key is generated from the password it will always be the same. But I do generate a random 32 byte salt each time I re-encrypt the file which should provide a different key each time. I would assume that a 32 byte salt would change the KEK significantly so that the zero initialized IV would not pose an issue for GCM. Is this a valid assumption?

Comment: Yes, you are right. And don't forget to pass the salt used at encryption along with the ciphertext, otherwise you won't be able to derive the key from the password for decryption, later.

Comment: @Lery thanks! I am already saving the salt together with the ciphertext so the file can be decrypted later. I was worried about the IV because I am currently not changing it. Is there a security risk for relaying only on the salt to change the encryption key?

Comment: No, the salt will significantly alter the outcome of scrypt. If anything you should look if you can tweak the work factor of scrypt to be as high as workable. And with anything password related, a strong password is still required. A 32 byte salt is - by the way - rather overkill; 16 bytes should be plenty (then again, it doesn't hurt much either, so...).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks for confirming my gut feeling! You make a good point. I will lower the salt size to 16 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the key only once, then there is no danger of reusing a nonce with the same key because you're not even reusing the key!

A collision in the salt and password would lead to the same key, but though the probability of such a collision may be nonzero, it is nevertheless negligible for a 32-byte salt—unless, of course, you roll back your VM state and get the same initial RNG state, or equivalent.

Do make sure to use AES-256, by the way, and not AES-128, if you want a 128-bit security level.